# Apply Bootstrap CSS and JS to Specific <div> Class when <article> Has Class "Bootstrap"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

The title pretty much says it all.  I am attempting to apply Bootstrap's CSS/JS **only** to `div`'s with the class "bootstrap", but *only* when the `<article>` element has the class "tag-load-bootstrap".

So, in the following code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <article class="tag-load-bootstrap">
      <div class="bootstrap"></div>
      <div></div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap's CSS/JS would be applied to the first `div`, but not the second.  I've tried going about this a number of different ways (e.g., jQuery, LESS), but haven't had much luck yet.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Given the requirements of this particular site, an iframe isn't an option.

**Update**: Here is a link to a page on which I am attempting to get this working: http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/12/21/writer-pro-for-os-x-and-ios/.  As you can see, the links at the bottom of the page are designed with Bootstrap in mind, but the Bootstrap CSS/JS are not being applied.  I've tried two separate ways so far:

1. I used an @import in my site's custom CSS file (i.e., coreyjmahler-com.css) and directed it at bootstrap.less, which in turn references the Bootstrap CDN.  I'm uncertain as to why this didn't work, but it didn't.
2. Currently, the site has a `<link>` in the `<head>` to the aforementioned bootstrap.less file, which retains the references to the Bootstrap CDN.  This, as you can see, is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a really bloated css, but using LESS:

```
.tag-load-bootstrap > .bootstrap{
    @import "bootstrap.less";
}
```

Instead I would suggest only extending the pieces of code you need.

As for the JavaScript, just use whatever you need on a specific element, either with the data attributes or programmatic API.

Comment: I added a bit more information, as I wasn't able to get this particular solution working.

Comment: When you are trying to @import a CDN, the file you are trying to import is a css file, but LESS can only import .less files, so it can preprocess them. So you have to download Bootstrap to your computer and preprocess it locally if you want to alter it in any way, like what I explained above.

Comment: I downloaded the LESS files and then uploaded them to my server.  I now have the bootstrap.less file called in the header for the site (`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/css/bootstrap.less" />`), but it doesn't seem to be loading and I'm not certain why.

Comment: LESS is a preprocessor, you can't sub it with css files. You need to work with it locally, on your computer, not on the server. You compile the css on your computer and only upload the css to the server.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, LESS files can be used on a site as long as you have a LESS processor, no?  I believe that's what I have in this: `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.0/less.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful, if you give a link to a jsfiddle with a demo code in it.

But, based on the info you gave, I might instead use the css selector:

```
.tag-load-bootstrap .bootstrap { /*css here*/ }
```

Comment: In lieu of creating demo code, I edited the original question with a link to a live page where the issue can be seen.